# How do I set the color of the Text in the parsetree in IntellJ with the ANTLR v4 grammar plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, antlr4

The [Antlr v4 Grammar plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7358-antlr-v4-grammar-plugin) is awesome when you are building Antlr Grammars.   The ANTLR Preview works perfectly, other than the parse tree (due to my dark theme) that is displayed is showing the node text in "Black" on "Black".

How do I change that Text?   I looked on the plugin site and found a ticket that says they map the color of the node to "textText", but I can't find that anywhere in IntelliJ